# Formatting duration as "hh:mm:ss" and write to pandas dataframe and to save it as CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv, timedelta

I imported data from a CSV file to `pandas` dataframe.

Then, created a duration column by taking difference of 2 `datetime` columns and which is as follows:

```
df['Drive Time'] = df['Delivered Time'] - df['Pickup Time']
```

Now, I want to save it back to the CSV file but I want the 'Drive Time' column to be displayed as "hh:mm:ss" format while I open using Excel. And the code I used as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("1554897620.csv", parse_dates = ['Pickup Time', 'Delivered Time'])

df['Drive Time'] = df['Delivered Time'] - df['Pickup Time']

df.to_csv(index=False)

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

*In Conclusion, I want to save Drive Time column in the format "hh:mm:ss" while exporting to CSV*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately no effect, if check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) it is same like `the ugly` way :(

Comment: OK. Let me try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that `Delivered Time` is never greater than 24 hours, you can use this trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Delivered Time', 'Pickup Time'])
df['Delivered Time'] = pd.date_range('2019-01-01 13:00', '2019-01-02 13:00', periods=12)
df['Pickup Time'] = pd.date_range('2019-01-01 12:00', '2019-01-02 12:00', periods=12)
df['Drive Time'] = df['Delivered Time'] - df['Pickup Time']

# Trick: transform timedelta to datetime object to enable strftime:
df['Drive Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Drive Time']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

By transforming the timedelta to a datetime data type, you can use its strftime method.